# Где нужно создавать переменную с ManyToMany field?

Tags: python, django

Как я понял, когда создаешь модель с Many2Many field, то создается дополнительное поле в базе данных, поэтому без разницы, где пишешь переменную с M2M field.

Это допустим у нас есть 2 модели: Book и Author. Нам нужно чтоб в Book было поле с authors и в Author было поле Books. Тогда, как я понимаю, без разницы где создать поле M2M field?

Comment: *создается дополнительное поле в базе данных* вообще-то создается доп таблица а не поле. А так по сути без разницы в какой модели вы определите эту связь

Comment: Пон спасибо &:!:₽: